# Can enemies see me through smoke?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Sometimes, enemies throw smoke grenades, meaning I can't see or target them (without [help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55888/3610)), but can they see *me* back? Does it affect their targeting/aim at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can and will still continue to target/fire.

> Be alert when moving through the smoke, as enemies will continue to fire through it, and the positions and numbers of enemies on the other side can change dramatically.

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Centurion

I do not have any specific details on if it affects their aim, but I doubt it does.

Comment: yeah, they seem to completely and utterly ignore smoke. Wouldn't surprise me

Comment: Corollary: Can my squad-mates see through smoke?

Comment: Good question. I think I saw that as a separate question, but I don't have an answer. I mostly focused on smoke in multiplayer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because they are simply AI, and know your whereabouts at all times whether or not there is smoke or a wall between you and them. This goes for any game that includes enemies. If the enemies are computer controlled/AI they will always know your current location, although they might not react that way.

Comment: That's incredibly misleading. A computer opponent's programming may have access to your position, but not all games exploit it to let the AI "cheat".

Comment: If the AI is a part of a pre programmed game then yes, it does know where your position is at all times, like I said though; they might not show that form of reaction towards the player.

Comment: "Know" is a rather broad term in this case. The AI may exist in the same environment as your position data, but unless it actually accesses that data, it doesn't know where you are. It is not unfeasible for AI to require having detected you before it will access it.

Comment: Yeah, this is misleading; plenty of games would impair the AI in this situation.  I think it's clear what you mean here, but I don't think that's what the question is actually asking.